# karma polymer test using phantomjs failing in elementSetup

Tags: phantomjs, polymer, karma-runner

I am trying to use karma-polymer-test to see if it will work with the polymer elements along with angularjs. i have the bolierplate html test js file and the element in the same directory.

My test:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
elementSuite('seed-element', 'boilerplate', function() {
    suite('attributes', function() {
        test('testing polymer element', function(done) {

        });
    });
});
}());
```

bolierplate.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Polymer Element Test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- Make sure the web components polyfill is loaded -->
<script src="../../public/bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
<script src="../../public/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<seed-element>
<p>This is <content/></p>
</seed-element>
</body>
</html>
```

Karma conf:

```
    frameworks: [
        'requirejs',
        'polymerTest',
        'jasmine'
    ],

  files: [
        {pattern:'test/polymer/*.html', included: false, watched: true, served: true},
        'test/polymer/*.js'
  ],

    polymerTest: {
        platform: 'public/bower_components/platform/platform.js',
        src: [
            'public/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'
        ]
    },
```

Error while running karma:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) ERROR
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'elementSetup.bind(this, name, boilerplate)')
at /Users/212437040/dev/APM_Code/Avid/apm-application/node_modules/karma-polymer-test/elementSuite.js:141
```

Anybody has any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS < v2 doesn't implement the Function.prototype.bind function. You'll need a shim for that.

[This shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521) works for versions before 2 and it is not necessary anymore for versions 2.0.0 onwards.

Comment: I have little experience with karma and polymer as to suggest you a way to apply this shim.

Comment: Thanks. I did install the poly from the url you have given and refered to the function.js in my boilerplate <script> but i am still having the same issue. Any idea how to apply? i did the npm install to get the shim.